# What is the difference between Xの数人 and 数人のX?

Tags: grammar

"私の友人**の数人**が今年日本へやってきた。"

"部屋には**数人の**学生がいた。"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple:

- **学生の数人**: some of the students
  (You're picking some members from a bigger group)
- **数人の学生**: some students